# Bad return type in lambda expression:

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```java
List<CategoryWiseEarnings> data = tripEarnings.getOrders()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(getCategoryRulesEarnedList -> getCategoryRulesEarnedList.getCategoryRulesEarnedList().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> foo.getCategoryId()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue()
               .stream()
               .reduce((c,c2) -> new CategoryWiseEarnings(
                   new CategoryWise(
                       c.getCategoryName(), 
                       c.getCategoryId()
                   ), 
                   c.getBonus()
               ))
    )
    .map(f -> f.get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Getting Exception as

> :Bad return type in lambda expression: `CategoryWiseEarnings` cannot be converted to `CategoryWise`

```java
public class CategoryWiseEarnings {

    @JsonProperty("category")
    private CategoryWise earnings;

    @JsonProperty("total_amount")
    private String totalAmount;

}
```

```java
public class CategoryWise {

    @JsonProperty("category_id")
    Long categoryId;

    @JsonProperty("category_name")
    String categoryName;

    public CategoryWise(String categoryName, Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }
}
```

This is my code which I want to write using streams and lambda function it is working fine if I write like this:

```java
for (Trips tripsOrders : tripEarnings.getOrders()) {

    if (!tripsOrders.getCategoryRulesEarnedList().isEmpty()) {

        for (CategoryWise c : tripsOrders.getCategoryRulesEarnedList()) {

            if (hashMapCategory.containsKey(c.getCategoryId())) {

                // hashmapk.put(c.getCategoryId(),new CategoryWiseEarnings(new CategoryWise(c.getCategoryName(),c.getCategoryId()),c.getBonus()+hashmapk.get(c.getCategoryId()).getTotalAmount()));
                CategoryWiseEarnings categoryObject = hashMapCategory.get(c.getCategoryId());
            
                categoryObject.setTotalAmount(Double.toString(
                    Double.parseDouble(c.getBonus())
                  + Double.parseDouble(categoryObject.getTotalAmount())
                ));

                hashMapCategory.put(c.getCategoryId(), categoryObject);

            } else {
                hashMapCategory.put(c.getCategoryId(), new CategoryWiseEarnings(new CategoryWise(c.getCategoryName(), c.getCategoryId()), c.getBonus()));
            }
        }
    }
}

List<CategoryWiseEarnings> list = new ArrayList<CategoryWiseEarnings>(hashMapCategory.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Stream::reduce(BinaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) expects a [`BiFunction<T, T, T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) while in the OP's code this contract is broken: `(CategoryWise c, CategoryWiseEarnings c2) -> new CategoryWiseEarnings()`

Also, the data model seems to be improper: in `CategoryWiseEarnings` field `total` should be `Double` to avoid redundant conversions, class `CategoryWise` is missing `bonus` field.

So, the solution could be to use `Collectors.groupingBy` and [`Collectors.summingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) together to calculate total values in a map, and then re-map the map entries into `CategoryWiseEarnings`:

```java
List<CategoryWiseEarnings> result = tripEarnings.getOrders()
    .stream() // Stream<Trips>
    .flatMap(trips -> trips.getCategoryRulesEarnedList().stream()) // Stream<CategoryWise>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        cw -> Arrays.asList(cw.getCategoryId(), cw.getCategoryName()) // key -> List<Object>
        LinkedHashMap::new, // keep insertion order
        Collectors.summingDouble(cw -> Double.parseDouble(cw.getBonus()))
    )) // Map<List<Id, Name>, Double>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new CategoryWiseEarnings(
        new CategoryWise(e.getKey().get(0), e.getKey().get(1)), 
        String.valueOf(e.getValue()) // assuming the total is String
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```